# testdriven.io How do I fix "Name or service not known" during docker run?

Tags: python, docker

testdriven.io

```
docker build -f project/Dockerfile.prod -t registry.heroku.com/mighty-savannah-85236/web ./project
```

Successfully built 3df1e0c4eea4

Successfully tagged registry.heroku.com/mighty-savannah-85236/web:latest

```
docker run --name fastapi-tdd -e PORT=8765 -e DATABASE_URL=sqlite://sqlite.db -p 5003:8765 registry.heroku.com/mighty-savannah-85236/web:latest
```

> nc: getaddrinfo for host "web-db" port 5432: Name or service not known

docker-compose file

```
services:

  web:
    build: ./project
    command: uvicorn app.main:app --reload --workers 1 --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
    volumes:
      - ./project:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 8004:8000
    environment:
      - ENVIRONMENT=dev
      - TESTING=0
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@web-db:5432/web_dev        
      - DATABASE_TEST_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@web-db:5432/web_test  
    depends_on:   
      - web-db

  web-db:
    build:
      context: ./project/db
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    expose:
      - 5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your container is trying to connect to `web-db:5432` which given the port likely is a Postgres database server. And as `web-db` is not a real domain most likely what happens is, that there should be another container called `web-db` which probably should be a Postgres database which your container wants to connect to.

This connection will only work though if both containers - the one you are starting and the Postgres database container - are in the same **user-defined Docker network** as only then **Docker service discovery** works. You might wanna have a look at the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/#use-user-defined-bridge-networks) for this.

But essentially you need to create a Docker network using

```sh
docker network create my-network
```

and then attach both containers - again, your container and the Postgres database - to that network using the `--network` option.
Additionally your Postgres container must be called `web-db` so that the service discovery will work.

So the skeleton of the command to start the DB would be the following:

```
docker run --name web-db --network my-network -p 5432:5432 your-database-image
```

The command to start your application would be

```
docker run --name fastapi-tdd --network my-network -e PORT=8765 -e DATABASE_URL=sqlite://sqlite.db -p 5003:8765 registry.heroku.com/mighty-savannah-85236/web:latest
```

Might also be worth exploring [Docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) to simplify this whole process.

### Edit

Now with your `docker-compose.yaml` file the same rule applies. Both containers need to be in the same user-defined network bridge, which can be declared using `networks:` (be aware: don't put it into `services:`).

```yaml
services:

  web:
    build: ./project
    command: uvicorn app.main:app --reload --workers 1 --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
    volumes:
      - ./project:/usr/src/app
    # attach this container to the network
    networks:
      - my-network
    ports:
      - 8004:8000
    environment:
      - ENVIRONMENT=dev
      - TESTING=0
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@web-db:5432/web_dev        
      - DATABASE_TEST_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@web-db:5432/web_test  
    depends_on:   
      - web-db

  web-db:
    # attach this container to the network
    networks:
      - my-network
    # name this container web-db
    container_name: web-db
    build:
      context: ./project/db
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    expose:
      - 5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres

# declare the network ressource
networks:
  my-network
```

Now a connection should be possible. Be aware that you also need to configure PostgreSQL correctly to allow you to connect to it setting `listen_address='*'` in `postgresql.conf`.

Comment: yes I have a docker-compose file already.

Comment: Ah ok, even better :) but the same rule applies. You need a network which you attach to both of those containers. I'll edit my post using the compose file you have just posted.

Comment: If you already have a Compose file, do you need the separate `docker` commands (you can `docker-compose build && docker-compose up -d`)?  Compose provides a network named `default` (see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) and `docker network ls` will show it for you, so if you do need a `docker run --net` option, you don't need to manually create a separate network.

Comment: Yes of course. This is now a bit misleading as the question was quite heavily edited and first did not mention a docker-compose file at all.

Comment: @user2373505 please approve the answer if this worked for you :)

Comment: @Mushroomator the solution fits but I discovered there is a different matter causing the error and I am still investigating. I will share the scenario with you just in case I am missing out on something.